# whats the most common mistake for having a CSS 100% height div?

Tags: html, css

Alrighty,

I'm going to try to explain what I have going on. Let me know if you need more information.

Basically, I have a div container, and I have it styled at `height:100%;` It will do 100% but it will only be 100% for the current browser/window size.

For example: if I maximize the browser, the container will do 100%, but if I scroll down, that container's height only goes as much as whatever the browser height was.

Another example: if I minimize the browser to a certain size and refresh the page, the container will go 100% again to the window size only. So if I maximize the browser, the height container will still be the same height has if the browser was minimize.

So if I have a long page, the container doesn't go all the way down to the page, the container only goes so far as the window's height size when the page loads.

I'm trying to get the container to go all the way 100% till the bottom of the page, even if I have a footer or header, the container should be 100% between the two.

So I'll try to post up the most relevant code:

```
body,html
{
   display:block;
   position:relative;
}
#container_100percent
{
   overflow-x:hidden;
   position:relative;
   overflow-y:auto;
   width:20%;
   min-height:100%;
   height:100%;
   float:right;
}


<div>
  <div id="container_100percent">
     <!-- some stuff !-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you set the body and html to relative position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of 100% is the height of his parent.

This means: if the parent div-container has no height, the height will be set to 100%, too and same for body. This is why your div has the height of your window.

So you need to give your div wrapper a height and the inner div will take on this height.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the container to be as high as its contents, don't set the `height` property. It's as simple as that.

If, however, you want it to have a minimum height (i.e. you never want to let it be less high than the window) set the `min-height` property.

Comment: I'm not trying to set the height of the content inside. I'm trying to set the height outside of the container. So if theres content in <div>, then the <div id="container_100percent"> should be the height of the parent. min-height does not give me this effect

Comment: Then I obviously don't quite understand what you want. You say "if there's content in `<div>`...", but there is: `<div id="container_100percent">` is the content. So can you do a jsFiddle or a screenshot or whatever that shows what goes wrong?

Comment: Yea, well I'm talking like as if there is content inside #container_100percent and the parent container. So for instance, you're saying don't set the height property of #container_100percent because it'll only do height of the content. Thats corret, but I want it to be able to be the height of the parent. So essentially, I shouldn't set the height of the parent huh?

Comment: Again, can you do a jsFiddle or a screenshot or whatever that shows what goes wrong?